# Equivalent of `const` reference to private class members in Python

Tags: python, oop

I understand that in Python there is no real notion of private/protected/public class members. Yet, using underscores this can be achieved to some extents. For example, consider an object that is supposed to count the number of even integers on a stream.  The following would be a relatively safe implementation

```
class EvensCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0

    def __call__(self, n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            self._count += 1

    @property 
    def count(self):
        return self._count
```

This way, the user cannot accidentally change `count` for example in the following way:

```
    counter = EvensCounter()
    counter.count = 5          # Gives AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I used to see this as an equivalent of defining `count` as a `private` member variable in C++ and then having only a getter that returns a `const reference` to the private member variable.

However, I realize that the above is not exactly correct.  Suppose instead of a simple `int`, `count` was of a more sophisticated type of `MyInt` defined as follows:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0

    def inc(self, n=1):
        self._value += n

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

 class EvensCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = MyInt()

    def __call__(self, n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            self._count.inc()

    @property 
    def count(self):
        return self._count
```

In this case, the following piece of code would work and effectively modify the `count` value:

```
    counter = EvensCounter()
    counter.count.inc(5)
```

While the user cannot change `_count` variable to reference another object, it can still call methods of that object that change its state.  (Whereas in C++, because the `inc()` method is not a `const` method, it cannot be called on a const reference.)

I was wondering if there is a mechanism in Python that provides same safety guarantees as the const references of C++?  Namely, I need a way to expose a reference to a (private) member of the class that only allows the user to 'read' that member variable, but does not permit him to change the state of that member variable.

Comment: As you have found out, Python has no ``const``. If you want to expose a non-mutable reference to an object, you have to create one yourself (e.g. with a proxy type that only has non-mutating methods). Note that you *still* cannot prevent clients from taking the non-mutable proxy object and extracting the underlying mutable object.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no such thing. C++ is the only major language that supports it (by "major", i mean "top 10 in market popularity", don't want to start a flamewar). Python obviously has no `const` concept, but even in language that do, `const` prevents you from re-assigning the variable, but not changing the object it refers to.

So, the main distinction in most languages is whether the object returned to is *mutable* or *immutable* as your two examples already illustrate. There's nothing you can do but hope that users respect your API.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.  Python's philosophy for preventing users from shooting themselves in the foot is "Hey, try not to shoot your foot please."  With some effort, you can add in some extra safeties, but you won't be able to stop users who point at their foot and pull the trigger.

Does your member need to be a reference?  Returning a deep copy will at least prevent the private member from being unintentionally modified.

You could also handle the const-ness yourself.  For example:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0
        self._is_locked = True

    def inc(self, n=1):
        if not self._is_locked:
            self._value += n
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Stop trying to modify the value outside of EvensCounter, dummy!')

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

class EvensCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = MyInt()

    def __call__(self, n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            self._count._is_locked = False  # If I were *actually* writing code like this, I would make this a context manager
            self._count.inc()
            self._count._is_locked = True

    @property 
    def count(self):
        return self._count
```

You could also *maybe* return a proxy that uses something like [frozendict](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/) under the hood, but I think that is susceptible to the same issue that you mentioned where nested members can be modified.